# Multiple issues; using infinity as a range, then followed by a 'list not been callable'

Tags: python, list, infinity

only just started coding as part of my honours project (civil engineering) and have hit a few problems, probably due to a complete lack of understanding.

first of all getting error with line 27-TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

by using a normal number just to proceed i then got a further issue, line 86-TypeError: 'list object is not callable.

any help is much appreciated.

i have taken a few screenshots as the code is quite long...i appreciate it is probably horrendously messy.

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Oiqy.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Ycd.png)

[3rd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnjZa.png)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! In its current form, it is difficult to answer your question. I would suggest to have a look at [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `for n in range(1, math.inf):` What do you expect this loop to do? Have an infinite number of iterations??

Comment: For the first part you can use `import itertools; for n in it.count(1)`.